# My program tries to find a specific color on the screen but returns a tuple error [Python3]

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I'm trying to complete [this](http://games.co.za/ant-smash.html) game using python, I'm a beginner, can anyone explain why my code isn't working please?

This is some of the code:

```
 box = (x_pad+1, y_pad+1, x_pad+731, y_pad+550)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=box)
    im.save('/Users/CENSORED/full_snap__.png')
    colour = (58, 15, 8)
    img = Image.open('/Users/CENSORED/full_snap__.png')
    rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')
    for x in range(rgb_img.size()[0]):
        for y in range(rgb_img.size()[1]):
            r, g, b = rgb_img.getpixel((x, y))
            if (r,g,b) == colour:
                print('found image at {x}, {y}')
                pyautogui.click(x,y)
                time.sleep(.1)
```

This is the error:

```
 File "/Users/CENSORED/Documents/Testing/gamecrusher.py", line 32, in <module>
    for x in range(rgb_img.size()[0]):
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Having grabbed the image, you save it to disk, then you read it in again. Why do that when you still have it in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rgb_img.size` is a tuple, not a callable method, so you don't put parentheses after it. You want:

```
for x in range(rgb_img.size[0]):
```

Likewise for `y`.